# Firing event when text is deselected/highlighted

Tags: jquery

jQuery has an event "selected". But is there an event that fires when the text is deselected?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any deselected event but there's probably only a couple events that will allow text to be deselected, so you can probably listen for blur, mousedown, and keydown.